# Date continuity in a database (find missing date gaps)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, gaps-and-islands

I have a database of users who pay monthly payment. I need to check if there is continuity in these payments.
For example in the table below:

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id |    date    |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 2015-02-01 |
|       2 | 2015-02-01 |
|       3 | 2015-02-01 |
|       1 | 2015-03-01 |
|       2 | 2015-03-01 |
|       3 | 2015-03-01 |
|       4 | 2015-03-01 |
|       1 | 2015-04-01 |
|       2 | 2015-04-01 |
|       3 | 2015-04-01 |
|       4 | 2015-04-01 |
|       5 | 2015-04-01 |
|       1 | 2015-05-01 |
|       2 | 2015-05-01 |
|       3 | 2015-05-01 |
|       4 | 2015-05-01 |
|       5 | 2015-05-01 |
|       1 | 2015-06-01 |
|       2 | 2015-06-01 |
|       3 | 2015-06-01 |
|       5 | 2015-06-01 |
|       3 | 2015-07-01 |
|       4 | 2015-07-01 |
|       5 | 2015-07-01 |
+---------+------------+
```

Until May everything was ok, but in June user 4 didn't pay although he paid in the next month (July).
In July users 1 and 2 didn't pay, but this is ok, because they could resign from the service.
So in this case I need to have information "User 4 didn't pay in June".
Is it possible to do that using SQL?

I use MS Access if it's necessary information.

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: And what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: And how do you know that uses resign?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: It sounds like a `Gaps and Islands` (per user) problem. Efficient solutions depend on DBMS you use.

Comment: As Vladimir already wrote, it's a "Gaps and Islands" problem. Especially in regads to the "Gaps" part, the problem is quite challenging. See for example [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) to get more understanding about the problem.

I don't think you will be able to manage the problem in MS Access SQL alone.

Comment: what if all of your user_id doesn't pay a specific month?

Comment: krish: It's possible. I want to find all such gaps.

Comment: can you post your table definitions for user table, payment tables

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: table definition means, your table layout how its structured. I asked, so i could replicate very near to your system. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a simple query for this but I realize that it's not the best solution. Other solutions are still welcome.

```
SELECT user_id,
       MIN(date) AS min_date,
       MAX(date) AS max_date,
       COUNT(*) AS no_of_records,
       round((MAX(date)-MIN(date))/30.4+1,0) AS months,
       (months-no_of_records) AS diff
FROM test
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING (round((MAX(date)-MIN(date))/30.4+1,0)-COUNT(*)) > 0
ORDER BY 6 DESC;
```

Now we can take a look at columns "no_of_records" and "months". If they are not equal, there was a gap for this user.

Comment: I'm suspicious of `(MAX(date)-MIN(date))/30+1 as months` as it seems to assume all months have 30 days. Perhaps [`DateDiff('m', MAX(date), MIN(date))`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php)?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, you cannot just work with paid in table to fill the gaps. If in case all of your user does not pay a specific month, it is possible that your query leaves that entire month out of equation.

This means you need to list all dates from Jan to Dec and check against each user if they have paid or not. Which again requires a table with your requested date to compare.

Dedicated RDBMS provide temporary tables, SP, Functions which allows you to create higher level/complex queries. on the other hand ACE/JET engine provides less possibilities but there is a way around to get this done. (VBA)

In any case, you need to give the database specific date period in which you are looking for gaps. Either you can say current year or between yearX and yearY.

here how it could work:

1. create a temporary table called tbl_date
2. create a vba function to generate your requested date range
3. create a query (all_dates_all_users) where you select the requested dates & user id's (without a join) this will give you all dates x all users combination
4. create another query where you left join all_dates_all_users query with your user_payments query. (This will produce all dates with all users and join to your user_payments table)
5. perform your check whether user_payments is null. (if its null user x hasn't paid for that month)

Here is an example:

[Tables]

1. tbl_date : id primary (auto number), date_field (date/Time)
2. tbl_user_payments: pay_id (auto number, primary), user_id (number), pay_Date (Date/Time) this is your table modify it as per your requirements. I'm not sure if you have a dedicated user table so i use this payments table to get the user_id too.

[Queries]

1. qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user:

   SELECT Year([date_field]) AS mYear, Month([date_field]) AS mMonth, qry_user_payments_user_group.user_id
   FROM qry_user_payments_user_group, tbl_date
   ORDER BY Year([date_field]), Month([date_field]), qry_user_payments_user_group.user_id;
2. qry_user_payments_paid_or_not_paid

   SELECT qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user.mYear, 
      qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user.mMonth, 
      qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user.user_id,
      IIf(IsNull([tbl_user_payments].[user_id]),"Not paid","Paid") AS [Paid?]
   FROM qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_user_payments ON (qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user.user_id = tbl_user_payments.user_id) 
           AND ((qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user.mMonth = month(tbl_user_payments.[pay_date])  AND (qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user.mYear = year(tbl_user_payments.[pay_date]) ))  ) 
   ORDER BY qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user.mYear, qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user.mMonth, qry_user_payments_all_month_all_user.user_id;

[Function]

```
Public Function FN_CRETAE_DATE_TABLE(iDate_From As Date, Optional iDate_To As Date)
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : FN_CRETAE_DATE_TABLE
' Author    : KRISH KM
' Date      : 22/09/2015
' Purpose   : will generate date period and check whether payments are received. A query will be opened with results
' CopyRights: You are more than welcome to edit and reuse this code. i'll be happy to receive courtesy reference:
' Contact   : krishkm@outlook.com
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'

    Dim From_month, To_Month As Integer
    Dim From_Year, To_Year As Long
    Dim I, J As Integer
    Dim SQL_SET As String
    Dim strDoc As String
    strDoc = "tbl_date"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)

    SQL_SET = "DELETE * FROM " & strDoc
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_SET


    If (IsMissing(iDate_To)) Or (iDate_To <= iDate_From) Then
        'just current year
        From_month = VBA.Month(iDate_From)
        From_Year = VBA.Year(iDate_From)

        For I = From_month To 12
            SQL_SET = "INSERT INTO " & strDoc & "(date_field) values ('" & From_Year & "-" & VBA.Format(I, "00") & "-01 00:00:00')"
            DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_SET
        Next I
    Else
        From_month = VBA.Month(iDate_From)
        To_Month = VBA.Month(iDate_To)
        From_Year = VBA.Year(iDate_From)
        To_Year = VBA.Year(iDate_To)

        For J = From_Year To To_Year
            For I = From_month To To_Month
                SQL_SET = "INSERT INTO " & strDoc & "(date_field) values ('" & J & "-" & VBA.Format(I, "00") & "-01 00:00:00')"
                DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_SET
            Next I
        Next J

    End If

    DoCmd.SetWarnings (True)

    On Error Resume Next
    strDoc = "qry_user_payments_paid_or_not_paid"
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, strDoc
    DoCmd.OpenQuery strDoc, acViewNormal
End Function
```

you can call this public function from button or form or debug window:

```
?FN_CRETAE_DATE_TABLE("2015-01-01","2015-10-01")
```

this will generate from jan to oct and check whether you received payments or not.

[Screen]:
[image: user payments table]

Comment: I would like to know the performance issues when running this query @maro

Comment: Thank you for your effort and expanded answer but it's too complicated for me.

Comment: practice and learn.. eventually you will get there one day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, look for user where next month is not paid for, but the month after that is paid for:

```
select user_id, month(date) + 1
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                    and month(t2.date) = month(t1.date) + 1)
  and exists     (select 1 from tablename t3
                  where t3.user_id = t1.user_id
                    and month(t3.date) > month(t1.date) + 2)
```

**Note 1:** No dbms is specified, so `month()` function is just pseudo code. ANSI SQL has `extract(month from column_name)`.

**Note 2:** in ANSI SQL `date` is a reserved word and needs to be delimited as `"date"`.

**Note 3:** Just realized this answer will only return the first month even if several (consecutive) are missing...

Comment: I checked your query but it shows an empty table... I use MS Access and the are no errors but the table is empty.